# How can I insert complex horizontal bar labels in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following sample dataset. The basis is a survey conducted at two time points. The survey results are differentiated by two groups (group1 and group2):

```
df <- structure(list(label2plot = c("yes", "no", "yes", "no",
"yes", "no", "yes", "no"), gruppe = c("group1", "group1",
"group2","group2", "group1", "group1", "group2", "group2"), 
cohort = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("20172018", "20192020"), class = "factor"), var_abs = c(4979L,
 3214L, 129L, 130L, 5476L, 3556L, 89L, 74L), var_rel = c(0.789565,
 0.8035, 0.871622, 0.8125, 0.793163, 0.805254, 0.839623,
 0.860465)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

From this, I create bar charts. For each group, there is a separate chart that I place side by side.

```
var_label <- "blabla"
title <- "blublub"
subtitle <- "blablub"
val_label <- c("yes", "no")

packages2check <- c("ggplot2", "stringr")

for (package in packages2check) {
  if (!requireNamespace(package, quietly = TRUE)) {
    install.packages(package)
    library(package, character.only = TRUE)
  } else {
    library(package, character.only = TRUE)
  }
}

ggplot() +
  geom_bar (
    data = df,
    aes(
      x = factor(label2plot, levels = val_label),
      y = var_rel,
      group = cohort,
      fill = label2plot
    ),
    stat = "identity",
    position = position_dodge(),
    color = "white",
    linewidth = 0.5
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    labels = scales::percent,
    limits = c(0, 1.15),
    breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.2)
  ) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none",
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5,
                              size = 14,
                              face = "bold"),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
    plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("yes" = "#AFCDE4", "no" = "#389DC3")) +
  geom_text(
    data = df,
    size = 3,
    position = position_dodge2(preserve = 'single', width = 0.9),
    hjust = 0.5,
    vjust = -0.5,
    color = "black",
    aes(
      x = factor(label2plot, levels = val_label),
      y = var_rel,
      label = paste0(sprintf("%.1f", var_rel * 100), "%", "\n(N=", var_abs, ")")
    )
  ) +
  labs(
    subtitle = paste(subtitle),
    title = str_wrap(title, 45),
    x = var_label,
    y =  "",
    fill = ""
  ) +
  facet_wrap( ~ gruppe)
```

In the individual charts, the results for "yes" and "no" at both time points are displayed. There will be more time points in the future. However, since there are only two time points now, the results for "yes" and "no" are represented with two bars of the same color.

I can insert the labels for the time points (or cohorts) into the bars vertically as I want. However, the label is only displayed in the left of each respective bar, not in the right bar as well.

It should look like the example chart. How do I do that?
[image: It should look like this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bottom line: you need `position=` to be the same as previous, and can place them using `y = min(var_rel)/2`.

I'll shortcut a bit by bringing the `factor(.)` outside of `ggplot2`, define the `x=` and `y=` aesthetics in the main `ggplot(.)` call, and all geoms benefit from the simplification. One benefit of this is that by using `factor`, you are imposing specific *order* on the lebels. However, with mixed use of factors and non-factors (i.e., `fill=label2plot`) then how they are ordered in all portions of the plot may be inconsistent (e.g., a legend). Perhaps that doesn't apply here (yet?), but it's often a good practice to get into.

```r
gg <- df |>
  transform(label2plot = factor(label2plot, levels = val_label)) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = label2plot, y = var_rel)) +
  geom_bar (
    aes(
      group = cohort,
      fill = label2plot
    ),
    stat = "identity",
    position = position_dodge(),
    color = "white",
    linewidth = 0.5
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    labels = scales::percent,
    limits = c(0, 1.15),
    breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.2)
  ) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none",
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5,
                              size = 14,
                              face = "bold"),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
    plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("yes" = "#AFCDE4", "no" = "#389DC3")) +
  geom_text(
    size = 3,
    position = position_dodge2(preserve = 'single', width = 0.9),
    hjust = 0.5,
    vjust = -0.5,
    color = "black",
    aes(
      label = paste0(sprintf("%.1f", var_rel * 100), "%", "\n(N=", var_abs, ")")
    )
  ) +
  labs(
    subtitle = paste(subtitle),
    title = str_wrap(title, 45),
    x = var_label,
    y =  "",
    fill = ""
  ) +
  facet_wrap( ~ gruppe)
```

From here, we can simply do:

```r
gg +
  geom_text(
    aes(y = min(var_rel)/2, label = cohort),
    angle = 90, position = position_dodge2(preserve = 'single', width = 0.9)
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add a term to your plot along the following lines...

```
+ geom_text(
    data = df,
    size = 4,            #larger text
    position = position_dodge2(preserve = 'single', width = 0.9),
    hjust = 0.5,
    vjust = 0.5,         #to centre in bar
    angle = 90,          #write vertically
    color = "black",
    aes(
      x = factor(label2plot, levels = val_label),
      y = 0.4,           #may need to adjust position
      label = cohort)    #label required
  )
```